# Is it possible to bypass the new scope creation of the add_subdirectory() command?

Tags: cmake

I currently have the following architecture

```
`-- system
    |-- CMakeLists.txt
    |-- dll
    |   |-- CMakeLists.txt
    |   |-- UnixDLoader.cpp
    |   |-- ...
    |   `-- WinDLoader.hh
    |-- sockets
    |   |-- CMakeLists.txt
    |   |-- crossplateform_utils.h
    |   |-- ...
    |   `-- Udp.hh
    `-- threads
        |-- CMakeLists.txt
        |-- IMutex.hh
        |-- ...
        `-- WinThread.hh
```

My root `CMakeLists.txt` is as follow

```
project(system)

add_subdirectory(dll)
add_subdirectory(sockets)
add_subdirectory(threads)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HEADERS}
    ${${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCES}
)
```

and in `threads/` for example, I have the following

```
list(APPEND ${PROJECT_NAME}_HEADERS
    IThread.hh
    UnixThread.hh
    WinThread.hh
    IMutex.hh
    UnixMutex.hh
    WinMutex.hh
)
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_HEADERS ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HEADERS} PARENT_SCOPE)

list(APPEND ${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCES
    UnixThread.cpp
    WinThread.cpp      
    UnixMutex.cpp
    WinMutex.cpp    
    PARENT_SCOPE
)
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCES ${${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCES} PARENT_SCOPE)

if(UNIX)
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} pthread)
endif(UNIX)
```

but, as `add_subdirectory()` creates a new scope, my `${PROJECT_NAME}_*` variables are empty. I read about `set(... PARENT_SCOPE)`, but the paths become invalids and anyhow cmake produces an error on the call to `target_link_libraries()` in `system/threads/CMakeLists.txt` saying `Cannot specify link libraries for target "system" which is not built by this project.`. Scope issue again.

So I though I would be nice if I found a solution to bypass the scope creation, but I'll take any solution that keeps the logic of my architecture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a couple of reasonable options here I think.

The `add_subdirectory` command is often used to include a directory (it needn't actually be a subdirectory in the filesystem sense) which really contains a standalone module, e.g. a library or executable; one which can be built without the help of a parent CMakeLists file.  In this case, the submodule's CMakeLists.txt would contain its own `project` command, rendering the use of a global `${PROJECT_NAME}` variable difficult.

In your case, it appears that you simply want the subdirectories' CMakeLists files to append lists of files to variables defined in the parent scope.  You can achieve this by making use of the CMake variable [`CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#variable:CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR) in your subordinate CMakeLists:

```
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_HEADERS
    ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HEADERS}
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/IThread.hh
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/UnixThread.hh
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/WinThread.hh
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/IMutex.hh
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/UnixMutex.hh
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/WinMutex.hh
    PARENT_SCOPE
)

set(${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCES
    ${${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCES}
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/UnixThread.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/WinThread.cpp      
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/UnixMutex.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/WinMutex.cpp    
    PARENT_SCOPE
)
```

Ensure you *don't* have a `project` command in your subdirectories' CMakeLists files.

This can be made slightly simpler in this case by swapping the `add_subdirectory` command with the [`include`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:include) command, hence avoiding scoping issues.

To do this, remove the `PARENT_SCOPE` args from the `set` commands, and in the top-level CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_subdirectory(dll)
add_subdirectory(sockets)
add_subdirectory(threads)
include(dll/CMakeLists.txt)
include(sockets/CMakeLists.txt)
include(threads/CMakeLists.txt)
```

Your other issue relating to `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} pthread)` is simply down to the fact that the `add_library` command defining the library `${PROJECT_NAME}` is called *after* the `target_link_libraries` command.  Your simplest option is probably to move the `target_link_libraries` command to the parent CMakeLists.txt